# Bash Find Null values of all variables after equal sign in a file

Tags: bash

I have a configuration(conf.file)  with list of variables and its values generated from shell script

```
cat conf.file
export ORA_HOME=/u01/app/12.1.0
export ORA_SID=test1
export ORA_LOC=
export TW_WALL=
export TE_STAT=YES
```

I want to find any variable has null value after equal(=) symbol, if so, then report the message as Configuration file has following list of null variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use awk for this:

```
awk -F"[= ]" '$3=="" && NF==3 {print $2}' conf.file
```

That will split each record by a space or an equal sign, then test the third field in each row. If it's empty, it will print the second field (the variable).

UPDATE: Added in a test for Number of Fields (NF) equal to 3 to avoid null rows.

Comment: Thanks, but this returns null rows as well
`awk -F"[= ]" '$3==""{print $2}' conf.file
ORA_LOC
TW_WALL


AN_STAT


onenode11/acvociordbu006a-> awk -F"[= ]" '$3==""{print $2}' conf.file |wc -l
7
`

Comment: Bingo..Thnx JNevill

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
awk -F"=" '$2'   Input_file
```

As you need after = a field shouldn't be empty so making = as a field separator and checking if 2nd field is not empty then no action defined in my code so default print action will happen for any line which satisfy this condition. Let me know if this helps.

**EDIT:** Above will give only those values whose values are NULL after =, thanks to JNevill for letting me know that requirement is exactly opposite, following may help now in same.

```
awk -F"=" '!$2{gsub(/.* |=/,"",$1);print $1}'  Input_file
```

Comment: This returns all variables with values. however my requirement is  to return only null variables with no null rows

Comment: no, this is not the case. I am getting only those values which have 2nd field after = value is present.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 The requirement is to return variable names that have no value. This returns values for variables that are set. It's very elegant, but it's exactly the opposite of what OP is wanting. Furthermore, from OP's example input file, there are clearly equal signs present for unset variables, so this won't work even if it matched requirements.

Comment: Thanks a TON JNevill for letting me know, I really missed it :(. updated my solution too now.